# Datepicker Month and Year Selected error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to build a datepicker that accepts only Month and Year, so i simply put hide the days with CSS using display:none and that's fine for me.
Then i change the datepicker options for user choose only Month and Year, and its work well.

For example, if i select **"JAN/2017"**, in input changes well.
But if you click on input again, it will be not **JAN/2017**, will be **SEP/2017**. Why?

Here is a plunker:  [CLICK HERE =)](https://plnkr.co/edit/AA4OW0q0dhVWyFZrTEkg?p=preview)

If you prefer to see Code, here you are:

```
  <body>
<style>
  .ui-datepicker-calendar {display: none!important;}
</style>

<input class="date-picker">

<script>
$('document').ready(function () {
        $('.date-picker').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM yy',
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
            }
        });

    })
</script>
```

Thanks a lot!

**@EDIT - SOLVED!**

I don't know if this is the best way, but worked!
I simply make some events manipulating DOM

```
        var mmNow, yyNow;

    $('document').ready(function () {
        $('.date-picker').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM yy',
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
            }
        }).click(function () {
            $('.date-picker').datepicker('setDate', new Date(yyNow, mmNow, 1));
        }).blur(function(){
            mmNow = ($('.ui-datepicker-month')[0].value)
            yyNow = ($('.ui-datepicker-year')[0].value)
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show, for example, 'Sep 2017' in your input, you should change your `dateFormat` to `M yy`, or to `M/yy` if you want the slash.

Comment: i think i was not clear... Try to put Jan/2017 and Confirm... Then click on input again... you will see that the input will be Sep/2017, and not Jan/2017. That's my problem. =/

Answer (score 0):

if you use this it should solve your problem except it will show date as well

```
dateFormat: 'MM/dd/yy',
```